# How to convert dlib .dat file to other ml model format?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, face-recognition, dlib, coremltools

Converting dlib model to torch or tf model and then Coreml model ?

I trying to convert dlib face_recongnition_resnet model to Coreml . But I don't have any ideas how to do so . Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I did it. I noticed seem function in [dlib example](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_introduction_ex.cpp#L164)
First you need clone dlib repository, and install all depends for build dlib.

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib/
sudo apt-get install cmake
#as dlib build instractions
sudo apt install libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev libavformat-dev
sudo apt install libavutil-dev
sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libswresample-dev

cd tools
mkdir dlib_to_xml
```

Okey, next we write program for saving caffee xml. Inspiring dlib example
I am not C++ guy but just using block working code.

```
nano save_to_xml.cpp
```

paste this

```
#include <dlib/dnn.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/clustering.h>
#include <dlib/string.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;


template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
using residual = add_prev1<block<N,BN,1,tag1<SUBNET>>>;

template <template <int,template<typename>class,int,typename> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN, typename SUBNET>
using residual_down = add_prev2<avg_pool<2,2,2,2,skip1<tag2<block<N,BN,2,tag1<SUBNET>>>>>>;

template <int N, template <typename> class BN, int stride, typename SUBNET> 
using block  = BN<con<N,3,3,1,1,relu<BN<con<N,3,3,stride,stride,SUBNET>>>>>;

template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares      = relu<residual<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;
template <int N, typename SUBNET> using ares_down = relu<residual_down<block,N,affine,SUBNET>>;

template <typename SUBNET> using alevel0 = ares_down<256,SUBNET>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel1 = ares<256,ares<256,ares_down<256,SUBNET>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel2 = ares<128,ares<128,ares_down<128,SUBNET>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel3 = ares<64,ares<64,ares<64,ares_down<64,SUBNET>>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using alevel4 = ares<32,ares<32,ares<32,SUBNET>>>;

using anet_type = loss_metric<fc_no_bias<128,avg_pool_everything<
                            alevel0<
                            alevel1<
                            alevel2<
                            alevel3<
                            alevel4<
                            max_pool<3,3,2,2,relu<affine<con<32,7,7,2,2,
                            input_rgb_image_sized<150>
                            >>>>>>>>>>>>;


std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> jitter_image(
    const matrix<rgb_pixel>& img
);

int main(int argc, char** argv) try
{

frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
shape_predictor sp;
deserialize("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat") >> sp;

anet_type net;
deserialize("dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat") >> net;


net_to_xml(net, "dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.xml");
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Then write build instructions in CMakeLists.txt

```
#
# This is a CMake makefile.  You can find the cmake utility and
# information about it at http://www.cmake.org
#

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)

set (target_name save_to_xml)

PROJECT(${target_name})

add_subdirectory(../../dlib dlib_build)

add_executable(${target_name} 
   save_to_xml.cpp
   )

target_link_libraries(${target_name} dlib::dlib )


INSTALL(TARGETS ${target_name}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    )
```

Then build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
and put there your model. I research dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat and shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat  these names written in cpp file

so run

```
./save_to_xml
```

and get your xml weights

Comment: or use this repo https://github.com/ksachdeva/dlib-to-tf-keras-converter.git